# How to find the average number of iterations for a variable to reach a number

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose I have an infinite loop with a variable x that starts at 0. Every iteration of the loop, x has a 10% chance of being increased by 1 and a 90% chance of being decreased by 1, but it cannot go below 0. How can I calculate the average number of iterations of the loop for x to reach a certain number?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @user2661923 I came up with it.

Comment: What are your ideas about it ? What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm not great at math and don't have any idea how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Personally, I am ignorant in this area, so I am unable to contribute analysis that will lead to an answer.  However, I can discuss/explain the negative reactions that your posting has received, so far.  You can use my comments, going forward, for this and any future MathSE postings.  So far, your posting has received one downvote, and two votes to close.  After five votes to close, your posting will be closed.  Then, your posting will not be able to receive further help.  ...see next comment

Comment: Since I regard the problem that you posted as interesting, and since you presented it very clearly, and since you originated the problem  and have no corresponding Math training, I feel that the negative reactions by MathSE reviewers are totally undeserved.  However, I am not (for example) allowed to upvote your posting to counteract a downvote that I disagree with.  All that I can really do is give you a very clear set of instructions that will allow you to avoid negative reactions by MathSE reviewers, in the future.  ...see next comment

Comment: Please read [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  Personally, given that you originated the question and have no corresponding Math training, I consider it onerous/ridiculous to apply the standards in the article to your posting.  However, reasonableness is not the point.  I am referring you to this article purely as a defensive measure.  If you follow the standards in the article, MathSE reviewers will almost certainly not react negatively to your posting, and will probably react positively, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MSE protocol, I can't give a full answer, but just to start you off, suppose you want to know the expected # of steps to get to $4$ on the natural number line from $0$,

we can start by writing$\;\;S_0 = 1+ 0.1S_1+0.9S_0$

This equation means that with one step from $0$, we either move with $Pr=0.1$ to step $1$ or fall back to step $0$ (since we can't go below $0$) with $Pr= 0.9$, and we can frame similar equations step by step, so the four equations will be

$S_0 = 1+ 0.1S_1+0.9S_0$
$S_1=1+0.1S_2+0.9S_0$
$S_2=1+0.1S_3+0.9S_1$
$S_3=1+0.9S_2$

The last equation means that
from $3$ either you get to $4$ with one step or fall back to step $2$

Why don't you try to solve this system of linear equations for $S_0$, and explore ?
And read about random walks ?